# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined in builder.js

Tags: javascript, typeerror, extra

Please help me regarding this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'model' of undefined" in Builder.js.
```

I'm using Extra theme from Elegant and I just updated my `Wordpress` to `Version 4.5`. When I tried to delete some sections in `Divi Builder` I got this error.

I don't know how to fix this. [Uncaugth Error Elegant Theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6l49.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before asking a question, please be sure to review the question in the preview box. Your current formatting is very difficult to read.

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm new here. :)

Answer (score 18):

I came across this error on the Divi Theme.
This is how I got it fixed... It will probably work for you as well.

Divi/includes/builder/script/builder.js

Replace these lines (2 total)

```
if ( view['model']['attributes']['parent'] === parent_id )
```

With these lines

```
if ( view !== undefined && view['model']['attributes']['parent'] === parent_id )
```

And replace these 2 functions

```
getNumberOf : function( element_name, module_cid ) {
    var views = this.get( 'views' ),
        num = 0;

    _.each( views, function( view ) {
        var type = view['model']['attributes']['type'];

        if ( view['model']['attributes']['parent'] === module_cid && ( type === element_name || type === ( element_name + '_inner' ) ) )
            num++;
    } );

    return num;
},

getNumberOfModules : function( module_name ) {
    var views = this.get( 'views' ),
        num = 0;

    _.each( views, function( view ) {
        if ( view['model']['attributes']['type'] === module_name )
            num++;
    } );

    return num;
},
```

With these

```
getNumberOf : function( element_name, module_cid ) {
    var views = this.get( 'views' ),
        num = 0;

    _.each( views, function( view ) {
        if(view !== undefined){
            var type = view['model']['attributes']['type'];

            if ( view['model']['attributes']['parent'] === module_cid && ( type === element_name || type === ( element_name + '_inner' ) ) )
                num++;
        }
    } );

    return num;
},

getNumberOfModules : function( module_name ) {
    var views = this.get( 'views' ),
        num = 0;

    _.each( views, function( view ) {
        if(view !== undefined){
            if ( view['model']['attributes']['type'] === module_name )
                num++;
        }
    } );

return num;
},
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thank you so much! The only google results I could find were for the theme which is structured differently than the plugin, this works great!

Comment: Works for Divi 2.4.3 , WP 4.7.5. Thanks!

Comment: I would change `view !== undefined` to `typeof view !== 'undefined'` as this could still result in an error.

Answer (score 5):

Roy Toledo answer works quite well for me, but i've replaced code in:

Divi/et-pagebuilder/js/admin.js

Divi version: 2.3.2

WP version: 4.7.1

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with the Divi theme (2.6) and WP (4.5). Same error message. An upgrade of the theme to the latest (2.7.3) fixed it in my case. The latest version of the Extra theme is 1.3.4 - looks like you are on 1.2.4.4

Comment: I see.. The problem with me is that I don't have the updated version. :(

Comment: for those that don't have a current ET subscription, in the spirit of Divi's GPL license, you can find a fix on [github for version 2.3.4](https://github.com/ajdruff/divi/releases) (the security patched version) that works with WordPress 4.5